# It is possible to skip the HTTP 202 response when using WS Addressing?

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

i am looking for ways to skip the HTTP 202 reponse send back by CXF when using WS Addressing. We need to support clients that are not capable of handling the HTTP 202 response. The operate in a request-response mode and are not able to handle the HTTP 202 returned by CXF.

Is there any way to skip the HTTP 202 reponse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP 202 indicates that the WS-Addressing structure is handling the incoming SOAP message as asynchronous. The trick is to give a good value for the ReplyTo property in the WSDL.

The ReplyTo (wsa:Replyto) element is used to select between synchronous and asynchronous behavior.  This element always includes a  element which is used to specify the address of the callback server.

For synchronous behavior, specify the Anonymous URL as the Callback URL.

```
<wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:ReplyTo>
```

For asynchronous behavior, specify the address of your application's callback server.

```
 <wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:Address>http://<server>/servlet/CallBackHandler</wsa:Address>
 </wsa:ReplyTo>
```

So using the anonymous url eliminates the HTTP 202

More information can be found here:

https://developer.connectopensource.org/display/CONNECTWIKI/Asynchronous+Web+Service+Calls+Using+WS-Addressing

and

http://developer.cisco.com/paws/PAWS_Developer_Guide/index.html?asynchronous_behavior.html